# how to use an image in css pseudo element ::after

Tags: html, css

How to add below blue image in front of every `<li>` i'm using `::before`

I want a structure like this

[image]

But I'm only be able to make this

[image]

This is my css code

```
.footer-top {

height: 346px;
background-color: #38464f;
padding-top: 56px;
}

.footer-top-ul {

padding-left: 0px;
}

.footer-top-ul li {

color: white;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: calibri;
line-height: 29px;
    width: 174px;
}

.footer-top-ul li::before {

content: "->";
padding-right: 6px;
}
```

I want to use that blue icon instead of "->"

And this is my html code

```
<ul class="footer-top-ul">
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Affiliate Programme</li>
<li>Careers</li>
<li>Gift Shop</li>
<li>Group Sales</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `url()`

```
.footer-top-ul li::before {    
  content: url(path-to-image);
  padding-right: 6px;
}
```

---

Another option is to use a HTML entity, like this, which will be more performant than an image

```css
.footer-top {
  height: 346px;
  background-color: #38464f;
  padding-top: 56px;
}

.footer-top-ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.footer-top-ul li {
  /*color: white;*/
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: calibri;
  line-height: 29px;
  width: 174px;
}

.footer-top-ul li::before {
  content: '\25B6';
  color: blue;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-top-ul">
  <li>About Us</li>
  <li>Affiliate Programme</li>
  <li>Careers</li>
  <li>Gift Shop</li>
  <li>Group Sales</li>
  <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Let me try this

Comment: @DipankarDas Thanks...I also added another option for your blue arrows

Comment: Thank you for these options, I think this one is a better option to use.